# How to set file path as a value in external properties file in spring

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd3Bp.png)

I have tried this.

Answer (score 0):

using file in spring needs to consider the absolute path and relative path. if u just want to use a file path, I think the last value you set (`logFileName`) is correct